# Neural networks by function examples -- how to get feeling of it?

Tags: artificial-intelligence, neural-network

I am looking for recommended books (or other materials, like web pages) which demonstrate such examples -- structure of neural network (artificial) for given function.

I.e. what is the best (in sense, of being minimalistic, yet correct) network structure for function *min* with N arguments. Or for function *abs*. And so on.

The reason for my question (**what books do you recommend?**) is I would like to get proper "feeling" how to shape the network to get the desired effect without overkill having dense network which computes correctly, but very inefficiently.

Answer (score 2):

There is no such thing as "the best NN structure". If you are lucky, you will find a structure that does the job, but that doesn't mean that that structure is the "best".

I highly recommend you reading  [Programming Collective Intelligence by Toby Segaran](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596529321). This book has a chapter on neural network. It explains many other artificial intelligence algorithms in a clear and concise way.

You may find additional wide reviews on neural networks [here](http://www.doc.ic.ac.uk/~nd/surprise_96/journal/vol4/cs11/report.html) and [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Artificial_neural_network#Further_reading)

<s>There is a lecture course on iTunes-U called ["Informatics for Nursing"](http://deimos3.apple.com/WebObjects/Core.woa/Browse/utah.edu.1471378404.01471378417) that contains several lectures dedicated to ANN's</s>

UPDATE June 2019: the iTunes-U course is no longer available and I couldn't find it elsewhere

Good luck